# Automated testing of Vagrant environments

Tags: testing, continuous-integration, vagrant, puppet

In many projects I use Vagrant with Puppet to have a copy of the live environment for development. Sometimes especially at small projects often I have to make a change, I re-provision the vagrant box and it fails!

Is there a possibility to test the Vagrant box using Continuous Integration?

I need to check that the box provisions without an error, and run some custom tests, such as opening a web page.

Comment: You could be asking a few different things here. Can you give an example of what you are trying to do?

Comment: I wann the CI to run a vagrant up check the exit-code and After that it should perform some custom Tests like call a webpage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Vagrant vs other choices for acceptance testing

Before I go into detail, Vagrant is definitely the choice for acceptance testing locally as it's super easy to setup. However, it's much harder to test in a CI environment, because you have to setup all the various pieces to get it working (Ruby, Vagrant, Virtualbox etc). Docker is a good choice as it's lightweight, and plenty of CI Tooling have Docker based testing built in (eg. Travis, Gitlab CI, CircleCI).

I go into detail [here](http://-%20https://petersouter.co.uk/running-puppet-acceptance-tests-in-docker-in-travis/) about using Docker. It's not perfect, as a container isn't a real machine: you can't test things like sysctl, or swap. But it's good for testing a basic Puppet module (package, config file service).

You have a two main choices on what to use to test your Puppet code:

## Beaker-rspec

Beaker is a tool written by the Release Engineering team at Puppet to test the Puppet Enterprise stack. Later [Beaker-rspec](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/5.0/bgtm.html#beaker-rspec) was born, to give a more rspec-like experience with Puppet module testing.

You write acceptance tests that look like this:

```
require 'spec_helper_acceptance'

describe 'cockpit class' do

  context 'default parameters' do
    # Using puppet_apply as a helper
    it 'should work idempotently with no errors' do
      pp = <<-EOS
      class { '::cockpit': }
      EOS

      # Run it twice and test for idempotency
      apply_manifest(pp, :catch_failures => true)
      apply_manifest(pp, :catch_changes => true)
    end

    describe package('cockpit') do
      it { is_expected.to be_installed }
    end

    describe service('cockpit') do
      # it { is_expected.to be_enabled }
      it { is_expected.to be_running }
    end

    context 'Cockpit should be running on the default port' do
      describe command('sleep 15 && echo "Give Cockpit time to start"') do
        its(:exit_status) { should eq 0 }
      end

      describe command('curl 0.0.0.0:9090/') do
        its(:stdout) { should match /Cockpit/ }
      end
    end
  end

end
```

Then you run the tests against a chosen "hypervisor". So in your case that would be vagrant, I'm assuming using Virtualbox.

You configure a host config file like so:

```
HOSTS:
  centos-72-x64:
    roles:
      - master
    platform: el-7-x86_64
    box: puppetlabs/centos-7.2-64-nocm
    hypervisor: vagrant
CONFIG:
  type: foss
```

Then invoke the test using environment variables to chose Puppet version to install and such (it will default to the latest release of Puppet and whatever box you've set as default):

```
$ PUPPET_INSTALL_VERSION="1.5.2" PUPPET_INSTALL_TYPE=agent BEAKER_set="centos-7-x64" bundle exec rake acceptance
/Users/petersouter/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/bin/ruby -I/Users/petersouter/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib:/Users/petersouter/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-support-3.5.0/lib /Users/petersouter/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/exe/rspec spec/acceptance
/Users/petersouter/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/beaker-rspec-5.3.0/lib/beaker-rspec/helpers/serverspec.rb:43: warning: already initialized constant Module::VALID_OPTIONS_KEYS
/Users/petersouter/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/specinfra-2.67.2/lib/specinfra/configuration.rb:4: warning: previous definition of VALID_OPTIONS_KEYS was here
Beaker::Hypervisor, found some vagrant boxes to create
==> centos-72-x64: VM not created. Moving on...
Bringing machine 'centos-72-x64' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> centos-72-x64: Importing base box 'puppetlabs/centos-7.2-64-nocm'...
```

There's a lot of output (I set my logs to verbose, but you can make it only show on failure also), but eventually you get a passing test:

Here's an answer on Beaker-rspec I gave on Serverfault:

- https://serverfault.com/questions/807316/puppet-test-roles-in-control-repo-with-beaker-rspec

Here's some other links explaining Beaker-rspec and Puppet:

- https://alexharv074.github.io/2016/05/13/setting-up-puppet-module-testing-from-scratch-part-ii-beaker-for-module-testing.html
- https://simp-project.atlassian.net/wiki/display/SD/Debugging+Acceptance+Tests+Using+Beaker

## Test-kitchen

test-kitchen is actually a Chef tool, but someone forked it to support Puppet (and Ansible). I haven't had as much experience with this, but essentially it works in a very similar way: you set up a configuration to test against, such as a Vagrant box, then write tests in the form of spec files:

```
require 'serverspec'

include Serverspec::Helper::Exec
include Serverspec::Helper::DetectOS

RSpec.configure do |c|
  c.before :all do
    c.path = '/sbin:/usr/sbin'
  end
end

describe package('ntp') do
  it { should be_installed }
end

describe service('ntp') do
  it { should be_running }
end
```

Here's a few good links sumarising:

- https://www.cedric-meury.ch/2016/10/test-driven-infrastructure-with-puppet-docker-test-kitchen-and-serverspec-yury-tsarev-gooddata/
- http://ehaselwanter.com/en/blog/2014/05/08/using-test-kitchen-with-puppet/